# Appending Data Into Existing Geometric Network

Tags: fme-form, geometric-network

I"m currently interning at a telecommunication company and have been tasked with converting their CAD maps into their GIS telecom model. I've been using FME to translate the CAD data with great success, but i've been roadblocked at the final step, which is appending the translated feature classes into the telecom model, necessary for the data to be uploaded to our Oracle database. The data that I'm outputting from FME is in simple line feature format and i'm trying to append these features to their corresponding empty feature classes that are in complex edge format. If you have any ideas please let me know.

Comment: Related: http://fmepedia.safe.com/AnswersQuestionDetail?id=906a0000000clIuAAI

Comment: Can you edit your question to provide more details about where your geometric network is stored and the telecom data model you are using, please?  Is it in an ArcSDE geodatabase!

Comment: The geometric network is stored within a standardized .gdb we use for every telecom exchange. The telecom data model is a data structure developed by ESRI and my company's network services staff for standardization of the network's spatial data.This translates to a set of feature classes nested in the geometric exchange, which have specific fields, data types and domains. I was able to replicate the fields, data types and domains, but haven't been able to resolve the issue of the geometric networks. It is not an ArcSDE geodatabase.

Comment: I figured it out. The incremental network loader did the trick.

Comment: I suggest you post some details of what worked for you as an answer and accept it so it benefits others in the future.